# Creating a user without a password on NetBSD

Tags: users, password, netbsd

On my NetBSD installation, I have it set so that root has no password. I can login as root without typing a password. But, when I create a user with just `useradd -m <username>`, log out, then enter `<username>` at the login prompt, I am asked for a password. Why is this? I'd like to login as `<username>` without a password. Why is this different than root, which logs in right after entering `root`?

Answer (score 0):

Having users without passwords is just a *bad* idea. Please assign passwords to all your users, especially "root". Every time you create a user without a password, a kitten dies.

On many systems, a good password is often the first, the last and the only line of defense against the scum of the Internet. Please tell me you haven't done that on a machine connected to network...

As far as asking a password, this is because the installation of NetBSD actually allows for password-less root, to be able to debug quickly a botched install. The NetBSD Manual is very specific about this and recommends you to run "passwd" as root immediately after installation.

[Take a look at the NetBSD Guide for more details.](https://netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-boot.html#chap-boot-login)

Comment: That's a great answer…if that had anything to with what I asked. I don't care about the security. It's a test VM. So can you please just tell me how to create a user that I can login to without a password? Many thanks if you do.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to look at the source for `useradd` to find out if it was even possible to specify no password.

The "easy" way to do what you want is to use `vipw` to edit the password file, possibly to add the user manually, or possibly after having used `useradd` to do the initial record entry, and all you have to do is delete everything in the password (second) field -- i.e. leave it empty.

See **passwd**(5) for details (i.e. `man 5 passwd`).